# What does the auto "t{1U}" do in the following range-based for loop from std::make_heap example?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-based-loop

I was browsing the standard algorithm library and came across an example which used a range based for loop in a way that I had not seen before: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_heap

In the example given, they use a range based for loop to iterate over the vector of integers:

```
for (auto t{1U}; auto i : v)
    std::cout << i << (std::has_single_bit(++t) ? " | " : " ");
```

I am familiar with the most commonly used range-based for loop. E.g.

```
for (const auto& elem : vector)
{
    // do something with elem
}
```

However, I was confused to see `auto t{1U}`, I had never seen that before and was wondering what the did?

It looks like it might be a temporary range expression:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
But I am still confused about what `t` actually is and also why it's needed here?

Comment: it's an init statement:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for, it simply declares a variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the range-based reference you yourself link to, you will see that the syntax contains a clause called *init-statement (optional)*.

`auto t{1U};` is that optional init-statement.

It's simply a way to define one or more variables inside the scope of the loop.

So

```
for (auto t{1U}; auto i : v)
    std::cout << i << (std::has_single_bit(++t) ? " | " : " ");
```

is basically equivalent to

```
{
    auto t{1U};  // The same as unsigned t = 1;

    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << (std::has_single_bit(++t) ? " | " : " ");
}
```

---

It might be worth noting that [the `if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) have had such a *init-statement* since the C++17 standard.